# SQLite Query Stops Incrementing at 10

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an insert query in an Android SQLite database. I need to keep a key id field that autoincrements for each new record. So as part of the setup to my insert command, I find the max value in this field and then increment it. It turns out that my code stops incrementing at 10. Everything is fine for the first 9 inserts, but I don't get higher than 10. What am I doing wrong???  Thanks!

Here the code:

```
public boolean createSubcategory(String subcategoryName) {
        
    int next;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    /* get the maximum value in the sub category table - this is the number to increment
     * and assign as the subcategory_id for our new subcategory record */
    cursor = db.query(SUBCATEGORIES_TABLE, new String [] {"MAX("+SUBCATEGORY_ID_COLUMN+") AS COL"}, null, null, null, null, null);

    /* Insert a row into the Subcategories table */
    if ( cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        next = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COL")) + 1;
    } else {next = 1;}
        
    newValues.put(SUBCATEGORY_ID_COLUMN, next);
    newValues.put(SUBCATEGORY_COLUMN, subcategoryName);
     
    db.insert(SUBCATEGORIES_TABLE, null, newValues);
    cursor.close();     
        
    System.err.println("New subcategory record created: ID: " + next + " Name: " + subcategoryName + "  Category ID: " + categoryID);
        
    return true;
}
```

Here is how I call this from MainActivity:

```
private void createSubcategories(myDB db) {
    db.createSubcategory("Jazz");
    db.createSubcategory("Orchestra");
    db.createSubcategory("Rock");
    db.createSubcategory("Wine Tasting");
    db.createSubcategory("Lectures");
    db.createSubcategory("Book Signings");
    db.createSubcategory("Basketball");
    db.createSubcategory("Baseball");
    db.createSubcategory("Football");
    db.createSubcategory("Hockey");
    db.createSubcategory("Other");
    db.createSubcategory("Incrementer Test");
}
```

And this is the output that I get. See how the subcategory_id stops at 10?

> New subcategory record created: ID: 1 Name: Jazz
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 2 Name: Orchestra
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 3 Name: Rock
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 4 Name: Wine Tasting
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 5 Name: Lectures
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 6 Name: Book Signings
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 7 Name: Basketball
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 8 Name: Baseball
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 9 Name: Football
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 10 Name: Hockey
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 10 Name: Other
>
> New subcategory record created: ID: 10 Name: Incrementer test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely that the search is made using lexicographical order, and since "9" comes after "10" in "ASCII-betical" order, your query always return 9 and next will always be 10.

Is your ID a string?

Comment: Thanks. I set the table up with that field as text. Duh.