# Incrementation stops at 10

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to increment values from csv file on inserting to mysql database, by incrementing every duplicate value by one.
So if I'm inserting 'processor-intel' to my database, if exists the value from csv will be incremented by 1. It will result in 'processor-intel1' and so on.
If I have for example 'nvidia-graphic-card' for 13 times in my csv but with different specs the incrementation works from 1 to 10 and the result will be:

```
'nvidia-graphic-card',
'nvidia-graphic-card1',
'nvidia-graphic-card2',
'nvidia-graphic-card3',
........
'nvidia-graphic-card9',
'nvidia-graphic-card10',
'nvidia-graphic-card10',
'nvidia-graphic-card10'
```

Why is incrementation stopped at 10 ?

This is the incrementation function I used:

```
  function increment_string($str, $separator = '-', $first = 1){
  preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $str, $match);

  return isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) : $str.$separator.$first;
```

}

I'm comparing every line from csv with database

```
$verificare = $database->select("SELECT alias FROM produse WHERE alias LIKE '%".$alias."%'");

for($x=0;$x<$database->countRows();$x++){
  if($alias == $verificare['alias'][$x]){
    $alias = $this->increment_string($verificare['alias'][$x], '-', 1);
  }else{
    $alias = $alias;
  }
}
```

This is the complete code for importing csv

```
    if($request->get($_POST["action"]) == "import"){

   $file = $upload->file_upload("import", "media/import");
   if(file_exists(DIR_UPLOAD_PHOTO . "/media/import/" . $file)){

        $file = DIR_UPLOAD_PHOTO . "/media/import/" . $file;
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");

        if ($handle) { 
            $lines = explode("\r", fread($handle, filesize($file))); 
        }  

        $total_array = count($array);

        $x = 0;

        foreach($lines as $line){

            if($x >= 1){
                $data = explode("|", $line);

                $titlu          = trim(addslashes($data[0]));
                $alias          = $this->generate_seo_link($titlu);
                $gramaj         = trim($data[1]);
                $greutate       = trim($data[2]);
                $pret_total     = trim($data[3]);
                $pret_redus     = trim($data[4]);
                $poza           = trim($data[5]);
                $pret_unitar    = trim($data[6]);
                $categorie      = trim($data[7]);
                $brand          = trim(addslashes($data[8]));
                $descriere      = trim(addslashes($data[9]));
                $vizibil        = trim($data[10]);
                $cod            = trim($data[11]);
                $nou            = trim($data[12]);
                $cant_variabila = trim($data[13]);
                $congelat       = trim($data[14]);
                $tva            = trim($data[15]);
                $stoc           = trim($data[16]);


                if($cod != "" && $cod != " "){

                    $verificare = $database->select("SELECT alias FROM produse WHERE alias LIKE '%".$alias."%'");   

                    for($x=0;$x<$database->countRows();$x++){
                        if($alias == $verificare['alias'][$x]){
                            $alias = $this->increment_string($verificare['alias'][$x]);
                        }else{
                            //$alias = $alias;
                        }
                    }




                    $database->insert(sprintf("insert into produse set 
                                                titlu='%s', 
                                                alias='%s',
                                                gramaj='%s', 
                                                greutate='%s', 
                                                prettotal='%s', 
                                                pretredus='%s', 
                                                poza='%s', 
                                                pretunitar='%s', 
                                                categorie='%d', 
                                                brand='%s', 
                                                descriere='%s', 
                                                vizibil='%d', 
                                                cod='%s', 
                                                nou='%d', 
                                                cant_variabila='%d', 
                                                congelat = '%d',
                                                tva = '%s',
                                                stoc = '%d'

                                                on duplicate key update

                                                titlu='%s',
                                                gramaj='%s', 
                                                greutate='%s', 
                                                prettotal='%s', 
                                                pretredus='%s', 
                                                poza='%s', 
                                                pretunitar='%s', 
                                                categorie='%d', 
                                                brand='%s', 
                                                descriere='%s', 
                                                vizibil='%d', 
                                                cod='%s', 
                                                nou='%d', 
                                                cant_variabila='%d', 
                                                congelat = '%d',
                                                tva='%s',
                                                stoc= '%d'", 

                                                $titlu, $alias, 
                                                $gramaj, $greutate, $pret_total, $pret_redus, $poza, $pret_unitar, $categorie, 
                                                $brand, $descriere, $vizibil, $cod, $nou, $cant_variabila, $congelat, 
                                                $tva, $stoc, 

                                                $titlu, $gramaj, $greutate, 
                                                $pret_total, $pret_redus, $poza, $pret_unitar, $categorie, $brand, $descriere, 
                                                $vizibil, $cod, $nou, $cant_variabila, $congelat, $tva, $stoc));    


                }
            }   
            $x++;
        }  



   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your alias column type is set to varchar ..change it to text.

[SQLite Query Stops Incrementing at 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698774/sqlite-query-stops-incrementing-at-10)

Answer (score 0):

your preg_match finds nvidia-graphic-card1 and is satisfied havin 1 as a number and does not check 10. It is called being [greedy or lazy](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch13_05.htm). 
Read up on it and rewrite your regex.

You can use [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) to easily test your regex statement.

this regex seperates your number from the rest of your result and gives you your number in $3:

```
$re = '/(.+)([^0-9]{1})([0-9]{1,})$/'; 
$str = 'nvidia-graphic-card10'; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

See this running [here](http://ideone.com/G7H1JB)

Comment: I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Is incrementing.. and stops at 10

Comment: The problem i think is in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the *"separator"* - it looks as though you could simply match a number at the end of the string - also *PHP* regex is greedy by default (not 100% sure what the other answer was getting at)?

```php
function increment_string($str){
    return preg_replace_callback('/\d*$/', function($match){
        return intval($match[0])+1; 
    }, $str, 1);
}
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/O1NC2C)

Comment: Thanx, But same results.

Comment: All functions posted here are working. I think the problem is with the sql query.